# assign value to element in list of lists python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
lis1 = [['name', 'lastname'], ['name', 'lastname']]
```

and the following list:

```
list2 = ['tom', 'miller', 'john', 'snow']
```

I want to have this result:

```
final_result = [[{'name': 'tom', 'lastname': 'miller'}], [{'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'snow'}]]
```

I am not sure how to do this while keeping the original `length` of `list1`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't you mean to use dictionaries instead? This is what they're for...

Comment: yes I guess a dictionary would be easier, I will update the question

Comment: @CeliusStingher not really, `dict` objects aren't really made to be used as records. A `tuple`, `namedtuple` or custom object (very easy with `dataclasses`) would be preferable.

Comment: Why the length of `list1`? Aren't the lengths of `list1` and `list2` supposed to match - so `list2` (which has no repetitions) can be used?

Comment: Also, why the name `lis1` and not `list1`?

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach using `iter`.

**Ex:**

```
lis1 = [['name', 'lastname'], ['name', 'lastname']]
list2 = iter(['tom', 'miller', 'john', 'snow'])

for i, v in enumerate(lis1):
    lis1[i] = {j:next(list2) for j in v}

print(lis1)
```

---

or using a list-comprehension

**Ex:**

```
final_result = [{j:next(list2) for j in v} for v in lis1]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'lastname': 'miller', 'name': 'tom'}, {'lastname': 'snow', 'name': 'john'}]
```

Comment: This is not OP's desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Rakesh's approach, but with a more concise code using `zip` and the `dict` constructor instead:

```
i = iter(list2)
final_result = [[dict(zip(l, i))] for l in lis1]
```

`final_result` becomes:

```
[[{'name': 'tom', 'lastname': 'miller'}], [{'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'snow'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your list version, you could do:

```
lis1 = [['name', 'lastname'], ['name', 'lastname']]

list2 = ['tom', 'miller', 'john', 'snow']

list_iter = iter(list2)

final_result = [
                 [f"{elem1}: {next(list_iter)}" for elem1 in inner_list] 
                 for inner_list in lis1
               ]

print(final_result)
```

Output:

```
[['name: tom', 'lastname: miller'], ['name: john', 'lastname: snow']]
```

For `dict` inside `list`:

```
>>> list_iter = iter(list2)

>>> final_result = [
                     [{elem1: next(list_iter) for elem1 in inner_list}] 
                     for inner_list in lis1
                   ]
```

Output:

```
[[{'name': 'tom', 'lastname': 'miller'}],
 [{'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'snow'}]]
```

And an extremely ugly looking way would be:

```
>>> [[dict(elem)] for elem in zip(*[zip(sum(lis1, []),list2)]*2)]

[[{'name': 'tom', 'lastname': 'miller'}],
 [{'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'snow'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your elements of list1 are repeating, so we can define `keys=list1[0]`.

Using this and list slicing notation, we can write:

```
final_result = [dict(zip(keys,l)) for l in list(zip(list2[0::2], list2[1::2]))]
```

which yields:

```
[{'lastname': 'miller', 'name': 'tom'}, {'lastname': 'snow', 'name': 'john'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `grouper` from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), you can do:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


list1 = [['name', 'lastname'], ['name', 'lastname']]
list2 = ['tom', 'miller', 'john', 'snow']

res = []
for k, v in zip(list1, grouper(list2, 2)):
    res.append(dict(zip(k, v)))
```

which produces:

```
print(res)  # -> [{'name': 'tom', 'lastname': 'miller'}, {'name': 'john', 'lastname': 'snow'}]
```